# Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I get this error while trying to add items to the combobox at runtime.Is there a way to add items on runtime , even if my combobox datasource is set .

Example:My combobox has items , but i want to display "Select Category" type of statement when my form loads .
Thanks !!!

Comment: @aF. Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

with EF

```
var list = context.Products.Where(x = > x.Active == true).ToList(); 
list.Insert(0, new Product() { Id = -1, Name = "Please Select" }); 
selectBox.DataSource = list;
```

The idea is to get your database list of objects into List < Product > () first, then simply add fake item on top of that list.

Comment: @RaggyShrestha If you could edit your question to add the type of object you are binding, then I'm sure b0rg could edit his own answer to specifically fit your case. Also, since it's always good to understand _why_ an answer does work, feel free to ask about any code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is display "Select Category", try this.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Category"));
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this after the DataBind() but I think it should be OK.